# Can I stop <a> action?

Tags: javascript

Basically if I have `<a href="" onclick="someFunction();"></a>` which will download a file. If the user says NO to `confirm("Do you agree?")` dialog, we don't want to let the user download this file.

This is all done with HTML and Javascript. All on client.

We want to kill the `<a>` to continue. Is it possible? Or can we deferred `<a>` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
return false;
```

in your function someFunction() which trigger in onclick event.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I didn't return in `onclick`. Thanks! Your solution is really the heart of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
function someFunction() {
  return confirm("Do you agree?");
}
```

Confirm function returns to user's answer, and someFunction return it to `<a>`'s onclick. If it false, it will be stopped to link to an href.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I didn't return in `onclick`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or use preventDefault:

```
function someFunction(e) {
   if (!confirm('.. ')) e.preventDefault();

  // continue download
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return false to onclick event.

```
function someFunction()
{
    if(confirm("Do you want to download now ?")) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return someFunction()">Click here</a>
```

Comment: `function someFunction()
{ return confirm("Do you want to download now ?"); }`
was enough

Comment: @swemon i'm not the downvoter, but you can remove the `if-else` condition and just return the value from the `confirm()` function.

Comment: @asgs thanks you. like function someFunction(){ return confirm("Do you want to download now ?")}??

Comment: @swemon yes, please refer Enes' post. The same exact thing they have answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction() {
 if(confirm("Do you want to download now ?") ) {
     // download file code goes here
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" onclick="return someFunction();">Test</a>

function someFunction() {
  if (confirm("Do you agree?")) {
    /* some code if YES */
    return true;
  }
  else {
    /* some code if NO */
    return false;
  }
}
```

Or:

```
<a href="" onclick="someFunction(event);">Test</a>

function someFunction(event) {
  if (confirm("Do you agree?")) {
    /* some code if YES */
  }
  else {
    /* some code if NO */
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    else event.returnValue=false;
  }
}
```